# basic knowledge of rate of change

Tags: integration

[image]

My answer for (a) is that the size of tumor decreases as time goes by. It could possibily because medical treatments are applied.  My answer for (b) is the tumor increases at start and decreases later because medical treatments are not applied in time.

Do I have the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

For a, what is $\ln(1)$, which is what you get when $V(0)=V_{max}$  For b, note that the log is of something greater than $1$ at the start.